# Suppress warnings in Visual Studio 2015 for custom code analyzers

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-analysis, fxcop

In Visual Studio, when you run Code Analysis on a project or solution, you can then [right click on the analysis warning/error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182069.aspx) and choose 'Suppress Message' to insert the `SuppressMessageAttribute` in your code.

From my own observations, this feature only seems to work for traditional FxCop/Code Analysis warnings.

Is it possible (or is there a Visual Studio extension) to provide similar functionality for the new [2015 Code Analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764967/visual-studio-2015-what-does-the-analyzers-reference-mean) (eg. for custom analysers installed via NuGet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1, and I have two Live Analyzers installed - SonarLint and CodeCracker. In my Error List window, I can right click on any warning and Suppress it in a Suppression File.
PFB the screenshots where I have suppressed a warning message from CodeCracker Analyzer into a Global Suppression File.

[image: Suppress Code Analysis Warnings]

[image]

Also VS 2015 Update 1 provides a great Code Analysis Feature where in you can view the warnings/messages **for only your code changes**. Selecting ‘***Changed Documents***’ filter in the Error Window will show the warnings pertaining to only the files where you have made modifications – and hence makes it lot convenient to use.

This is applicable to any LIVE code analyzers which you can add to your Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: Ha.. it looks like you are correct. My only quibble is that that if you choose the 'Suppress In Source' that it inserts #pragma directives. Fine if everyone is using 2015, but if you're working on code with people using older versions then you need to use the SuppressMessage attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(...)]
```

Comment: I already mentioned the attribute in my question. I'm asking about a UI feature in Visual Studio that will automate inserting the attribute