# missing analyzer reference C# visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, xamarin

i just installed VS 2015, and created a project with Xamarin Forms. When i create the solution all the projects are missing the Analyzer reference anyone know how to fix this?

[image: issue]

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764967/visual-studio-2015-what-does-the-analyzers-reference-mean

Comment: no, look the pic am missing the analyzer, so i cant debug or build

Comment: I believe that is normal to not have an Analyzer. That shouldn't stop you from building or deploying. What does your build output say?